# How to determine if query of SQL is too complex?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

In my c# application, the users can build dynamic reports from the SQL database.
I need to warn the users if their DB-query is too complex and takes too long to run.

I'm working with microsoft-sql-server 2008.

How can I do that?
Are there any statistic-algorithms to calculate the runtime of a query execution?

Comment: how would you define too complex?

Comment: you mean like sql server's query optimiser? I don't think you'll be writing one of those...

Comment: I think you mean "It's to expensive"

Comment: Open SQL profiler and view which queries are taking longer than a certain period or using to much memory etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is practically impossible. The database calculates execution-plans based on table and indices statistics and even the database itself cannot predict the runtime.

There might be some indications such as ordering (and grouping, which implies ordering) or several joins, but any algorithmic prediction is nearly impossible in my opinion.

Comment: How can I indicate the need og chenging  the order of the joins?

Comment: You should never need to modify the join order (theoretically) because the query optimizer should know it better than you. The optimal join order might change because the amount of tuples in a table changes (and so maybe the optimal join algorithm) and stuff. Clever indexing and evaluating execution plans is a better approach than forcing a specific join order. Nevertheless sometimes the database behaves strange (from my developer's point of view) because of insufficient statistics or design flaws and thus switching join orders can make sense. The only indication is an execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a formular, based on Factors like the number and types of joins, order by and where criteria but also the line-count of all tables affected.

Depending how that formular is build, that would give u a rough indication when a query gets to "heavy".

Answer (score 0):

As others are pointing out, the absolute answer is that you can't tell up front, how long a query will take to run.

The closest thing I could suggest, to try and give a **crude** idea of what is involved in the query before running it, is to first retrieve the estimated execution plan for it, and doing some crude analysis of that.

```
SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON
GO
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM MyTable
GO
```

In the execution plan XML, there is info like the estimated number of rows, whether the optimizer timed out before choosing an execution plan, what operations are performed (index seek/scan etc) and a whole ton of other stuff (you'd really need to dive deeper into execution plans).

So in theory, you could try and look at the info in the plan to make a crude/best guess judgement. Note it's only the estimated execution plan, and I don't know what level of accuracy/judgement you could make.

It doesn't give you time, just (maybe) some way to weigh up the relative anticipated cost of a query

Answer (score 0):

As the others already shown, you can't predict the complexity beforehand. All you can do is letting the query run and abort if it takes too long.

To abort the query after some time, you could take a look into the [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) and set it to some suitable value. The drawback of this approach that the user might wait the full time just to get an error message that the query simply took to long.

Another approach would be to let the user decide when it takes to much time. This can be done by using no limit (Timeout = 0), but [call the execute method asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a674khd.aspx) and simply provide a cancel button to the user he can hit.

This last approach would be the same as within the SQL Server Management Studio. If you start a query you'll see in the footer a running timer on how long the query is currently running and within the toolbar you have a cancel button to stop the currently running query.

Comment: Is it sounds reasonable to create stump tables that include a small percentage of the original db-tables.
 Now I'll run the queries first on this stump-tables (for run-time indication) and accordings to the viewed run-time I would estimated the real run-time of execution the query on the original db.. 
is it make sense?